# Teenage Boy gives Counselling Sessions in the Bathroom

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy, drama

I'm looking for a movie where

- the main protagonist is a high-school boy from a rich family.
- I think he transfers from private to a public school at the start of
  the movie and is not well liked because he stills wears his private
  school uniform.
- He has regular appointments with a shrink.
- But instead of discussing his problems he imitates the problems of
  his peers in school and even get drugs for these problems.
- In school then he holds counselling sessions from the bathroom and
  gives out those drugs.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to edit any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: [Identify-This-X Questions](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This sounds just like Infinite Jest, if you think it could have been from a book instead of a movie.  But I don't know how you could possibly forget that.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This sounds like [**Charlie Bartlett**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0423977/).

Let's look at the trailer...

- High school boy - Check
- Rich - Check
- Private to Public school - Check
- Wears uniform and not well liked - Check
- Psychiatrist - Check
- Giving counsel/drugs to fellow student in bathroom - Check

I don't what else it could be!

Comment: A similar trope was utilized to comical effect in a much earlier "Rock 'n' Roll High School" from 1979.